# How to make the second row of the second column be the same height as first column

Tags: javascript, html, css, bulma

I'm trying to build a layout which essentially looks like this (the blue line being the scroll bar)
[image: layout drawing]

But with how I have it right now the lower green box goes past the total height of the entire box. I've uploaded a rough version of what I have created onto [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLXwmE), I'm using the Bulma framework and essentially I want the lower box in the second column be a height where the total height of the left column equals the height of the right column.

So I want it to end where the black line is and have a scroll bar where the right hand side is.
[image: drawing]

I can set the height of the lower box to be a specific view height which fixes it a tiny bit and just set the overflow to scroll, but it gets messed up a bit if you try to resize.

At worst, I can do this with JavaScript by making the height of the lower box equal to height of `left column - height of top box` but I'm trying to see if there's a better CSS way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution: set `.column.is-2` to flex with direction column, set `#getHeight` `display: block` and make bottom one scrollable with `overflow: auto`. 
Codepen demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVJdgj

```css
html {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.fullh:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

.fullh:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0rem;
}

.fullh{
    margin-top: 0rem;
    margin-left: 0rem;
    margin-right: 0rem;
}

.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0,0,0,0.25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}

option:hover{
    background-color:#F1F6FE;
}

.is-vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.component-helper {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #74A2F8;
}

.component-helper:hover {
    color: #504A77;
}

.column.is-2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#getHeight {
  display: block;
}

.column.is-2 > .scroll {
  overflow: auto
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.2/css/bulma.css" />

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" />

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dashboard_script.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar is-transparent navbar-padding" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation" style="background-color: #fafafa">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a class="navbar-item nav-text" href="#" style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 1.5rem;color: #74A2F8;">
                    Test
                </a>
                <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-menu">
                <div class="navbar-end nav-text">
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Test
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Test
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-item">
                        Test
                    </a>
                    <a class="navbar-item" style="color:#f15870" href="/logout">
                        Test
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Primary Page Layout
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
    <section class="hero is-fullheight" style="background-color: #fafafa">
        <div class="columns fullh" style="height:92vh;">
            <div id="heightActual" class="column is-10">
                <iframe class="shadow" src="/" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%;height:100%;">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="column is-2">
                <div id="getHeight" class="columns">
                    <div class="column">
                        <div class="box is-vertical-center is-centered" style="height:100%;background-color: #fafafa;">
                            <div class="has-text-centered" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="component-helper" id="add">Add Components</li>
                                    <li class="component-helper" id="edit">Edit Components</li>
                                    <li class="component-helper" id="order">Order Components</li>
                                    <li class="component-helper" id="order">Add pages</li>
                                    <li class="component-helper" id="order">View Pages</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="columns scroll">
                    <div class="column">
                        <div id="heightFix" class="box is-vertical-center is-centered" style="background-color: #fafafa;display:block;">
                            <div style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 1.2rem;">
                                All
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 1.2rem;">
                                All
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 1.2rem;">
                                All
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="font-weight: 500;font-size: 1.2rem;">
                                All
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="columns is-desktop" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="column">
                                    <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/2f3761216d6940f8c535a80b1df3042e.png" alt="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Modal containing all the Elements -->
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="modal-background"></div>
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="box" style="width: 100%;">

            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks that works, is it possible to make the scroll inside the box, so like the box wouldn't get cut off from the bottom? [Like how it's cut off here](https://i.gyazo.com/5be138afcf776936f0771c5c6596b7ea.png)

Comment: @HelloMellow yes, I have added `margin-bottom: 0px;` to `.column.is-2 > .scroll`, updated on codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVJdgj

Comment: Hey! not exactly what I meant, I meant something more [like this](https://i.gyazo.com/d21ab910658a6a0a73dc0bf9b27e6f38.mp4), the overflow should fall on the box category I think (How I achieved it here doesn't exactly work because I set the height of the box to be something so it's not responsive)

Comment: @HelloMellow is this what you meant? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVJdgj

Comment: YES! Thank you so much!! Was stuck so long how to figure it out haha, thanks again! :)